# docker-compose environment variables inside container

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a small python app developed with docker containers.

My setup is:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3

ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy

ENV http_proxy ${http_proxy}
ENV https_proxy ${https_proxy}
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y vim screen
RUN \
    echo 'alias py="/opt/venv/bin/python"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo 'alias ls="ls --color=auto"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo 'PS1="\u@\h:\[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ "' >> /root/.bashrc
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
WORKDIR /app   
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

x-dev:
    &proxy_conf
    http_proxy: "${HTTP_PROXY}"
    https_proxy: "${HTTPS_PROXY}"
services:
    py_service:
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args: *proxy_conf
        image: ${APP_NAME}_img
        volumes:
        - '.:/app'
        restart: always
        command: tail -f /dev/null
```

**.env**

```
HTTP_PROXY=<http_proxy_server_here>
HTTPS_PROXY=<https_proxy_server_here>
APP_NAME=python_app
```

The problem is if the proxy server has changed i need to rebuild the image and i don't want that(as a last result maybe i will do it).

What i'm trying to do is change the proxy environment variables inside the container but i don't find the file where the env is stored.

The container OS version is:

```
[root@5b1b77079e10 ~ >>>] $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to recreate containers, not rebuild the image.  I assume you are doing something like this to get everything up initially:

1. `docker-compose build`
2. `docker-compose up -d`

Then I assume you are updating you .env file, once you do that you should be able to just do the following for your container to pick up the change:

1. `docker-compose down`
2. `docker-compose up -d`

You should not need to do a `docker-compose build` again.

Comment: You don't even need `docker-compose down`. `docker-compose up -d` is enough, the compose script will detect changes and recreate the container.

Comment: But proxy_server is stored in .env file and docker-compose up -d docker will recreate the image becouse something has changed. I am right ?

Comment: No, `docker-compose up -d` will only recreate the container not the image.

Comment: I don't have a another solution other than recreating container ? I am aware of the concept of ephemeral containers on docker, but i want to know where are stored the environments variable inside container.

Comment: Assuming we are talking about Linux containers then that is a linux question not really a docker question, but according to this they are stored in `/proc/1/environ`: https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-stored-the-environment-variables/65762

Comment: @nipuro Glad I was able to help.

Comment: I tested and I have to add then http_proxy variable env in docker-compose.yml so i don't need to rebuil the image.